# Add a message for aria-live/ accessibilityLiveRegion

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am editing a button that currently loads more products onto a page. A "Load More" button. For ADA compliance, when voiceover is on this button must say "loading" when clicked. I have injected aria-live/accessibilityLiveRegion into the component but it just reads "Load more Load more" when pressed... Can I add a message somehow to the aria live? Or any advice on how to get a button to read 'Loading' after pressed in React Native Web?

Comment: Can you provide an example? It might be easier for people to help if they have more info to go on.

Answer (score 0):

`aria-live` should be on the element that's going to be changing, if you don't already have it there. Or just add the attribute `role="alert"` to that element. It will automatically read out the content, so you could conceivably add a click handler to your button and give a screen reader only element with an alert role the content of "loading" to get the functionality you're describing.